# Privacy issue, links for sharing questions, answers contains user ID

Tags: feature-request, hyperlinks

please do not add user ID to the links given to users when they click to share the link to an answer (for example there: [Slow ext4 fsck](https://serverfault.com/questions/21424/slow-ext4-fsck/22216#22216) , yet i see that it does not happen in all sites/questions ). When you move the mouse over your profile buttons in the top right bar, you can see the user number in the browser bottom status bar.

When i post such link publicly i disclose my probable user ID that i have on this site, pairing my identity.

I would like to prevent this without need to always remember removing the ID from the URL.

I was checking [Firefox web browser addons](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/search/?q=clipboard%20replace) if there is any that modify clipboard contents but unable to find after quick look. I am using Linux currently, [there is something for it](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1167026/detect-clipboard-copy-paste-event-and-modify-clipboard-contents/1167129#1167129), but I have not tested it if it works as it does not seem much convenient.

Ideal would be if this tracking practice is removed.

Answer (score 4):

The way the "Share" links work is system-wide, so this request would have to be raised on the main Meta site, and there are already questions about it there.

The most [relevant post about this privacy leak](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74274/privacy-leak-in-permalink) is originally from 2011, with an update in 2019.  There are some workarounds mentioned, but the key point is probably in the first comment by a staff member: "...the permalink is explicitly designed to contain your ID..."